# links with page not working for Chrome android

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, hyperlink

links with page not working for Chrome android

```
<a href="#foo">Go To Foo</a>


<h1 id="foo">Hello Foo<h1>
```

It works for desktop Chrome. But it is not for android Chrome. Thanks.